# Presto fails to read hexadecimal string: Not a valid base-16 number

Tags: presto

Is there a way for presto to check if a string is hex or not? I have the following query keeps failing:

```
from_base(hexstring, 16)
```

with error

```
>     /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyhive/presto.py in _process_response(self, response)
>     347             self._state = self._STATE_FINISHED
>     348         if 'error' in response_json:
> --> 349             raise DatabaseError(response_json['error'])
>     350 
>     351 
> 
> DatabaseError: {'message': 'Not a valid base-16 number:
> ffffffffffdfae90', 'errorCode': 7, 'errorName':
> 'INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT', 'errorType': 'USER_ERROR', 'failureInfo':
> {'type': 'io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException', 'message': 'Not a valid
> base-16 number: ffffffffffdfae90', 'cause': {'type':
> 'java.lang.NumberFormatException', 'message': 'For input string:
> "ffffffffffdfae90"', 'suppressed': [], 'stack':
>
```

However, python is ok with the string:

```
int('ffffffffffdfae90',16)
```

returns

```
18446744073707433616
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from_base` [returns](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#) [`BIGINT`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#bigint) which can hold up to `2^63 - 1` i.e. `9223372036854775807` which is less then `18446744073707433616` while python's `int` is undounded, so this particular number is just too big for Presto.