PL/SQL to Superset/Trino - convert hexadecimal funcion
I'm trying to convert the following pl/sql statement to use in Superset/Trino:
select to_number(substr('D0023377B23DB783',-16), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') from dual; 

result: 14988599054092911360
In trino/superset I'm using the following statement but it doesn't return the right output
select from_base(substr('D0023377B23DB783', 2), 16) ;

return: 619539137935235
return  expected: 14988599099026945923
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance,
Ana
pl sql
select to_number(substr('D0023377B23DB783',-16), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') from dual;
result: 14988599054092911360
superset/trino
select from_base(substr('D0023377B23DB783', 2), 16) ;
return: 619539137935235
return  expected: 14988599099026945923

You are throwing away some meaningful digits, so your calculation becomes invalid. Ideally you should be able to convert the number as is:
select from_base('D0023377B23DB783', 16) ;

But since from_base returns BIGINT this number is too big (see Presto fails to read hexadecimal string: Not a valid base-16 number). One trick is to switch to DECIMAL and parse the number in parts. Something like the following can give you an idea:
select from_base('D0', 16) * cast(power(16, 14) as decimal) 
    + from_base('023377B23DB783', 16);

Output:
        _col0         
----------------------
 14988599099026945923


Thank you very much for your reply!
But it gives an error saying: trino error: Not a valid base-16 number: D0023377B23DB783
I've searched for a workaround and didn't find it
I've found this explaining why:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946854/presto-fails-to-read-hexadecimal-string-not-a-valid-base-16-number
Do you know if there is a workaround to get the bigger number?

@AnaPinheiroTorres you can do some math and parse it in parts, see the update.
